# FreeMaker - attach file with multiple functions

Tags: java, freemarker

I have file "myFunctions.ftlh" with multiple functions, e.g.:

```
<#function add x y>
    <#return x + y>
</#function>
```

and

```
<#function multiply x y>
    <#return x * y>
</#function>
```

and now, how can I attach this file into another templates and what is way that I can use these functions?

I tried to attach it something like: `<#import "Functions.ftlh" as my>` but it's does not work or I did something wrong

Comment: If you did that import, then you should be able to do things like `${my.add(1, 2)}`. What error message are you getting, or what exactly is wrong?

Comment: You are right, my bad, I used <@my instread of ${my, thanks